# How to read a pdf file in Vertx?

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-httpclient, vertx-eventbus, vert.x-webclient

I am new to VertX and I want to read a pdf using the "GET" method. I know that buffer will be used. But there are no resources on the internet on how to do that.

Comment: Where is this PDF file stored at first?
What have you tried so far?

Comment: The pdf file is in a couchbase DB. I am using webclient to get the pdf file. So I have to get the pdf and send it as a http response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omitting the details of how you would get the file from your data store (*couchbase DB*), it is fair to assume the data is read correctly into a `byte[]`.

Once the data is read, you can feed it to an `io.vertx.core.buffer.Buffer` that can be used to shuffle data to the `HttpServerResponse` as follows:

```java
public void sendPDFFile(byte[] fileBytes, HttpServerResponse response) {
    Buffer buffer = Buffer.buffer(fileBytes);
    response.putHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
            .putHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(buffer.length()))
            .setStatusCode(200)
            .end(buffer);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of storing it in byte[] array and then using Buffer.buffer() ?

Comment: Because `io.vertx.core.buffer.Buffer` is the internal data wrapper used by *Vert.x* to move data around and to achieve common data access interface. Additionally, using the specific `io.vertx.core.buffer.Buffer` type allows to pipe and stream data as needed instead of sending batched data.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.